# Python script, runs well, but not perfectly, debugging help

Tags: python

What it does (sort of)... or is meant to, the script reads from a csv file that contains information on sound files and create a play list exactly 60 minutes long.

An example csv, contains:

```
their title, duration (in seconds), minium total time to be played (in minutes)
```

An example is:

```
Soundfoo,120,10
Soundbar,30,6
Sounddev,60,20
Soundrandom,15,8
```

The script works out the minimum instances of plays, take 'Soundfoo' for example, the length of each sample is 120 seconds and the minimum time to be played is 10 minutes, so basic maths 10*60/120 gives the number of instances the song is to be played, in this case 5.

It is meant to take minimum number of instances and spread out equally from each other; so there will never be a period where for example Soundbar is played twice in a row.

Then if the minium instances of each song has been used, and there is still time with in the 60 min, how is it possible to tell it to go back and fill the time by selecting each sound and including it till the 60 min is filled while remaining sparsely populated.

**Heres the issue(s)!**

The script fails to calculate the actual time require to play all the sounds in a file and the total time of the playlist, **the thing is tho** it doesn't get it wrong all the time maybe 3/5 times, even if I run it on the same csv file it will give me different answers.

Here is the file I shall run the script on e for sake of ease to see the issue:

```
Sound1,60,10
Sound2,60,10
Sound3,60,10
Sound4,60,10
Sound5,60,10
Sound6,60,10
```

I'll do it three times and post the results:

*1*
    Required playtime in minutes: 60
    Actual time in minutes to play all required ads: 62
    Total playtime in minutes: 62.0

*2*
    Required playtime in minutes: 60
    Actual time in minutes to play all required ads: 71
    Total playtime in minutes: 71.0

*3*
    Required playtime in minutes: 60
    Actual time in minutes to play all required ads: 60
    Total playtime in minutes: 60.0

Relevant Code:

pastebin.com/demkBXk6

And finally... in context:

http://pastebin.com/demkBXk6

If you made it down to here, thanks for staying and reading, kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code several times and I got always the same result indicated below. I can not replicate your problem.

edit: sorry, yes now I see the problem.

The problem is in the first while loop
I would take away everything in this loop. The code is too convoluted and thus a call for bug. It can be done simpler and more clear:

If what you want is to randomly shuffle the list of required_playlist you only need to do

```
random.shuffle(required_playlist)
```

this will shuffle the list in place.
To fill the actual_plays dictionary then you can use a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
actual_plays = defaultdict(int)
for song in required_playlist: actual_plays[song] += 1
```

This obviously can be done before or after shuffling. In this step there is no way you could obtain different numbers of repetitions than the minimum you define.

cheers
joaquin

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has something to do with your use of the `random` library throughout the script.  Try to break your program up into functions that contain discrete bits of logic and are named to reflect what they do.